# Leaflet popups events through CartoDB

Tags: leaflet, carto, popup, events

How I can use the leaflet popups events through CartoDB. I have seen that some events are working like 'click', 'movestart',but 'popupclose' and 'popupopen' are not working. My goal is to do some tasks when the user closes the popup.

Can be the problem that I am using SVG in the infowindow?

I am using `cartodb.createVis` or should I use `cartodb.createLayer` instead?  am I not noticing something?

```
cartodb.createVis('map', url)
        .done(function(vis, layers) {
            layers[1].setInteraction(true);
            layers[1].on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data, layerNumber) {
                cartodb.log.log(e, latlng, pos, data, layerNumber);
            });

            var map = vis.getNativeMap();

            map.on('click', function(e) {
            });
            map.on('popupclose', function(e) {
                var marker = e.popup._source;
            });
            map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
                var marker = e.popup._source;
            });
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible 'workaround' could be [this](http://bl.ocks.org/xatpy/2bed06d2a65d85422339)

Basically, the 'trick' is to have a function that handles the infowindows visibility.

```
  var infowindow;
  var infowindowOpened = false;

  .done(function(vis, layers) {
      var layer = layers[1];
      infowindow = layer.infowindow;
      infowindowOpened = false;

      $('#map').click(closeInfowindow);

      layer.on('featureClick',function(e, latlng, pos, data, subLayerIndex) {
        infowindowOpened = true;
      });
    })

  function closeInfowindow() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!infowindowOpened) {
        infowindow.set('visibility', false);
        console.log('DO YOUR STUFF HERE');
      }
      infowindowOpened = false;
    }, 250);
  }
```